# How to recognize voice commands in iOS?

Tags: ios, swift

I am trying to do something similar to [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iR8lx15ir2c).

To summarize the video, the app continiously listens to you and when it recognizes words you specified (commands), it would announce you.

However, `NSSpeechRecognizer` works only for macOS.

Is there an equivalent for iOS? I tried `SFSpeechRecognizer` but I don't know how to specify the available commands.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`SFSpeechRecognizer` doesn't have commands.
So what you need to do is to create an array or set with command words and then check if it contains recognized word.

Please see http://avikam.com/software/sfspeechrecognizer-tutorial.

Comment: perfect! thanks a lot!

Comment: @user7852991 you are very welcome ;)

Answer (score 0):

SFSpeechRecognizer is one way of trying this, another is to try and create a Siri intent based upon a specific domain that you are targeting in iOS.  However, I am not positive that either of these options will get you to what you are looking for though because in the video you will see that the macOS application is open and listening to the dictation.

To continuously listening part is the problem.  You can enable Siri to do this by setting this up in your iOS settings and then training Siri, but as far as I know this capability is not available for SFSpeechRecognizer.  As I understand SFSpeechRecognizer, it is used primarily for dictation.